# Program can't find DLL header files after switching to release

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

After switching to release mode from debug mode (where everything works fine) I'm getting these errors:

```
Error   50  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CalculateGlassModel.h': No such file or directory   C:\Users\h6565169\Documents\anotherTPS2\G2GsiBridge\Development\Gsi\Gsi.cpp 10  1   Gsi
51  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "CalculateGlassModel.h"   c:\Users\h6565169\Documents\anotherTPS2\G2GsiBridge\Development\Gsi\Gsi.cpp 10  1   Gsi
52  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "nlopt.h" c:\Users\h6565169\Documents\anotherTPS2\G2GsiBridge\Development\Gsi\Gsi.cpp 11  1   Gsi
53  IntelliSense: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name   c:\Users\h6565169\Documents\anotherTPS2\G2GsiBridge\Development\Gsi\Gsi.cpp 88  2   Gsi
54  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Users\h6565169\Documents\anotherTPS2\G2GsiBridge\Development\Gsi\Gsi.cpp 88  27  Gsi
55  IntelliSense: identifier "gsi" is undefined c:\Users\h6565169\Documents\anotherTPS2\G2GsiBridge\Development\Gsi\Gsi.cpp 89  17  Gsi
```

I am working in VS 2013. The code generation is set to /MD for all my dll's. The platform toolset is Visual Studio 2013 (v120).

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Where is "CalculateGlassModel.h" ? Look at the include path for release and compare it to the debug settings?

Comment: A standard mistake is making project setting changes in the Debug configuration but forgetting to make them as well in the Release configuration.  Like the C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories setting.  Maybe some more, just use the combobox at the upper left to switch back-and-forth.

Comment: @HansPassant That was it, thanks!